# No output after trying loading data on the fly using Json and ajax

Tags: json, ajax

```js
var pageCounter = 1;
var animalContainer = document.getElementById("animal-info");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ourRequest.open('GET', 'https://learnwebcode.github.io/json-example/animals-1.json');
  ourRequest.onload = function() {
    if (ourRequest.status >= 200 && ourRequest.status < 400) {
      var ourData = ourRequest.responseText;
      renderHTML(ourData);
    } else {
      console.log("We connected to the server, but it returned an error.");
    }

  };

  ourRequest.onerror = function() {
    console.log("Connection error");
  };

  ourRequest.send();
  pageCounter++;
  if (pageCounter > 3) {
    btn.classList.add("hide-me");
  }
});

function renderHTML(data) {
  var htmlString = "";

  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    htmlString += "<p>" + data[i].name + " is a " + data[i].species + "</p>";

  }

  animalContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlString);
}
```

I have checked every thing and i don't know what is wrong with the code... I am trying to load information on the fly using Json and ajax

Comment: Please provide more information. Are there any errors in the developer console of your browser (as you are logging with `console.log` there should be)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not parse your data to JSON so what you have to do is parse your "ourData" to JSON.. Remove and add this line of to your code.

```
var ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
```